# JavaScript - Turning an array into a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, html-lists

I want to be able to turn an array, which consists of names entered by a user, into an unordered list but the list presents all the names on the first list item. How do I separate the names onto different list items?

This is what I currently have:

```
function createList(){
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var input = document.getElementById("q8").value;
    var strComma = input.split(",");
    console.log(strComma);
    var i = 0;
    for (i; i < strComma.length; i++){
        var el = document.createTextNode(strComma[i]);
        li.appendChild(el);
        list.appendChild(li);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do a trick

```
function createList(){
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    //var li = document.createElement("li");
    var input = document.getElementById("q8").value;
    var strComma = input.split(",");
    console.log(strComma);
    var i = 0;
    for (i; i < strComma.length; i++){
        var el = document.createTextNode(strComma[i]);
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(el);
        list.appendChild(li);
    }
}
```

That way you are creating new `li` element and appending to the same existing `ul` element. In your way, where you declared `li` outside loop, you just referenced the same `li` element every time.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now

Comment: Like and share... oh, oh... I mean upvote and accept ;) glad to help ;)

Comment: Trying to, need 15 reputation points to upvote and need to wait 3 mins to accept? Beginner problems

Answer (score -1):

HI you can use like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click the button to convert the array into a String.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
   var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
   fruits.toString();
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP asked how to turn it into an unordered list (`ul` tag). Also the `toString` call is useless.

Comment: you can put it in ul and li list.
Please append ul and li using js and use array

Comment: `Please append ul and li using js and use array` - well apparently he did that, he just needed his code adjusted a bit.